# How to redirect my custom module url after admin login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, module, custom, login

What I want:
Admin should redirect my custom module url('`adminhtml_module1/testimonial/index`') instead of dashboard page after successfully admin login.

Any idea ?
How  can I do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The redirect is done to the page selected in 
`System > Configuration > Admin > Startup Page`.

If you already defined a menu node for your admin page, you should be able to select it form the dropdown.

**Further information:**

The dropdown consists of system config values form the source model `adminhtml/system_config_source_admin_page`
built in 
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Admin/Page.php`

This iterates through all `<menu>` nodes from the admin config entries.

The corresponding XML config node is `admin/startup/page` where the corresponding URL for the redirect is retreived in `Mage_Admin_Model_User`.

The actual redirect happens in `Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController`:

```
/**
 * Admin area entry point
 * Always redirects to the startup page url
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $url = $session->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl();
    if ($session->isFirstPageAfterLogin()) {
        // retain the "first page after login" value in session (before redirect)
        $session->setIsFirstPageAfterLogin(true);
    }
    $this->_redirect($url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for best and deeply answer and If I change or set custom url as per your answer then any security admin login issue(admin login hacking problem) in future ?

Comment: This is more a question of how you defined the admin router.

Comment: Good explanation @AnnaVölkl +v1